# Possible to change the slug of default post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have custom post types on my wordpress site and I've set the slugs to say "/blog/{post_type}/{post_title}".

I'm using the default post type as a "notes" section, so I want that slug to be "/blog/notes/{post_title}".  Is this possible?

Comment: Guessing your post type is called something other than "notes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many »default post types« like `post`, `page` or even `nav_menu_item`. If you talking about `post` as the default just go to Settings → Permalinks admin page, chose »custom structure« and use `/blog/notes/%postname%/` as your structure.

Comment: Wouldn't that change the permalinks for all pages as well?

Comment: Tried this, but now all my custom post types permalinks are "/blog/notes/blog/{post_type}/{title}"

Comment: How do you define the custom post types? I guess you need to define the `rewrite => with_front` key to `FALSE`.

Comment: Ahh, that was what I was missing! That works great.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the structure in your Permalink settings and you can also change the slug in the code you used to register the post type and then re-save your Permalinks.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
```

In the above example, the slug is portfolio which can be changed.

Read more under the Rewrite section http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type