# change default 'post' slug with register_post_type_args

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to change the default `slug` for default wordpress `post`.

With `register_post_type` works fine with this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
function my_new_default_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'post', array(          
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),         
    ) );
}
```

But with recent `register_post_type_args` is not possible. This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'new_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function new_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'post' === $post_type ) {      

        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'blog';

    }

    return $args;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Singe 'rewrite' takes an array, you could try changing the args line to `$args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => 'blog');`

Comment: Related - you can just change permalinks rather than use the filter - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131666/possible-to-change-the-slug-of-default-post-type

Comment: @WebElaine that does not work. I think your code is the same that `$args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'blog'`